# Is my computer being hacked? Strange goings-on with menu.lst

Tags: malware

I installed my Kubuntu 12.04 in Windows with Wubi. I've never installed any other version of Linux on my Netbook, definitely not Tiny Core Linux. Yet I have the following lines commented out in my menu.lst file:

```
#title TinyCore Linux 
#kernel (hd0,2)/boot/bzImage 
#initrd (hd0,2)/boot/tinycore
```

I'm worried that this might be a symptom of a malware infection. There's been other suspicious activity too. Those lines appeared uncommented at the shell prompt while I was editing my menu.lst file:

> robert@ubuntu:/host/boot$ in
>   bash: syntax error near unexpected token `in'
>   robert@ubuntu:/host/boot$   title puppeee (on /dev/hda1)
>   bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('
>   robert@ubuntu:/host/boot$   root (hd0,0)
>   bash: syntax error near unexpected token `hd0,0'
>   robert@ubuntu:/host/boot$   kernel /peee/vmlinuz psubdir=peee pkeys=us

It looks like someone was trying to remotely overwrite the commented lines in my menu.lst file with uncommented ones while I had the menu.lst file open for editing but wound up writing the lines to the shell prompt instead.

Basically I'm worried that someone is using Tiny Core Linux to control my PC remotely. Are my fears warranted? Is there anything I can do to stop this?

Comment: It is extremely unlikely that this is a hacking attempt. What program were you using to edit your `menu.lst`? Sounds like you were trying to execute it instead of editing it. Also, Ubuntu has been using grub2 which does not have a menu.lst file since version 9.10. Where is this file you're editing?

Comment: Well that's a relief.

Comment: I was using Emacs to edit /host/boot/menu.lst . Thanks @terdon for your assistance.

Comment: Is it possible that you had selected text in emacs and then middle clicked on the terminal? That would have pasted the selected lines.

Comment: No, I'm on a laptop with a trackpad and no middle button to click.